# Merging Two Sorted Files with fstream

Tags: visual-c++, merge, ifstream, getline, ofstream

I am trying to take two sorted files with 5000 integers each and combine them into one file of 10000 sorted ints. I have it working except when the program finishes one of the files, printing out the rest of the other file.

Here is my method to merge two files

```
void mergeFiles(string inFile1, string inFile2, string outFile) {
        ifstream fin(inFile1);
        ifstream fin2(inFile2);
        ofstream fout(outFile);

        string line;
        int i = 1;
        int in2 = 0, in1 = 0;
        if(fin) {
            getline(fin,line);
            in1 = atoi(line.c_str());
        }
        if(fin2) {
            getline(fin2,line);
            in2 = atoi(line.c_str());
        }
        bool first = true;
        while(fin || fin2) {
            if(fin && fin2) {
                if(in2 <= in1) {
                    fout << i++ << ": " << in2 << endl;
                    getline(fin2, line);
                    in2 = atoi(line.c_str());
                }
                else {
                    fout << i++ << ": " << in1 << endl;
                    getline(fin, line);
                    in1 = atoi(line.c_str());
                }
            }
            else {
                            // This is the part giving me trouble
                            // Code Snippets below go here
            }
        }
    }
```

Depending on which I use this:

```
fout << i++ << ": " << line << endl;
if(fin)
     getline(fin, line);
else if(fin2) 
     getline(fin2, line);
```

The last 5 lines of my output file look like this:

```
9996: 99933
9997: 99943
9998: 99947
9999: 99947
10000: 99993
```

or

```
if(fin)
     getline(fin, line);
else if(fin2) 
     getline(fin2, line);
fout << i++ << ": " << line << endl;
```

The last 5 lines of my file look like this:

```
9996: 99933
9997: 99943
9998: 99947
9999: 99993
10000: 99993
```

The last 5 lines of my file are supposed to look like this:

```
9996: 99933
9997: 99943
9998: 99947
9999: 99957
10000: 99993
```

I know it has something to do with grabbing the next line from a file and the procedure of my algorithm. Any ideas on how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. I wasn't outputting the last integer on a file when it reaches the end. I was duplicating the integer of the other file twice, once when the first file ended and the second time when the file was false. Here is how I solved it:

```
    void mergeFiles(string inFile1, string inFile2, string outFile) {
    // Open Files
    ifstream fin(inFile1);
    ifstream fin2(inFile2);
    ofstream fout(outFile);

    string line;                // string to hold line from file
    int i = 1;                  // line counter
    int in2 = 0, in1 = 0;       // ints to hold ints from each file
    if(fin) {                   // if file is open
        getline(fin,line);      // get first line
        in1 = atoi(line.c_str());   // convert to int
    }
    if(fin2) {                  // if file is open
        getline(fin2,line);     // get first line
        in2 = atoi(line.c_str());   // convert to int
    }
    bool first = true;          // bool to catch when a file closes
    while(fin || fin2) {        // if either file is still open
        if(fin && fin2) {       // if both files are still open
            if(in2 <= in1) {    // file 2 has the smaller int
                fout << i++ << ": " << in2 << endl; // print file 2 int to output file
                getline(fin2, line);        // get next line from file 2
                in2 = atoi(line.c_str());   // convert to int
            }
            else {              // file 1 has smaller int
                fout << i++ << ": " << in1 << endl; // print file 1 int to output file
                getline(fin, line);         // get next line from file 1
                in1 = atoi(line.c_str());   // convert to int
            }
        }//endif
        else {      // if one of the files has finished
            if(first) {     // first time through the else
                if(!fin)        fout << i++ << ": " << in2 << endl;     // Depending on which file closed
                else if(!fin2)  fout << i++ << ": " << in1 << endl;     // print the int before printing lines
            }//endif
            else
                fout << i++ << ": " << line << endl;    // don't need to convert just print at this point

            // get the next line from the file that is open
            if(fin)         getline(fin, line); 
            else if(fin2)   getline(fin2, line);

            first = false;  // only print line from now on, don't print in1 or in2
        }// endelse
    }//endwhile
}//endmethod
```